# Pass parameter to ESPER EPL query?

Tags: java, parameters, runtime, esper

I am new to esper epl query.I want to know is it possible to change EPL query in run time.It means I have a form which can use to change the  time length,number of records in ESPER.It is simply like this,increase the time length in epl query,number of records in event.Likewise i want to change parameter in pragmatically.I want to know is this possible and if yes give me some hint to start.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual requirement you can use `Variables`.
From [Esper Docs](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/epl_clauses.html#variable_create):

> In addition to creating a variable via the create variable syntax, the
>   runtime and engine configuration API also allows adding variables. The
>   next code snippet illustrates the use of the runtime configuration API
>   to create a string-typed variable:
>
> ```
> epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().addVariable("myVar", String.class, "init value");
> ```

Then you can [use variables](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/epl_clauses.html#variable_using) in your queries. For instance (again from Esper docs):

> The next statement assumes that a variable named 'var_threshold' was
>   created to hold a total price threshold value. The statement outputs
>   an event when the total price for a symbol is greater then the current
>   threshold value:
>
> ```
>  select symbol, sum(price) 
>    from TickEvent  group by symbol having
>    sum(price) > var_threshold
> ```

So if you exactly know what you want to parametrize, then you can make your queries more dynamic.